# Pulling the first record of a history file for every unit

Tags: sql, db2

iSeries DB2  v6r1m0

I'm trying to pull the first record of a history file for every unit and then tie them into my main table, already containing other join logic.

Sample history file in full (assuming the table is already sorted by UnitTime (latest to oldest)

```
UnitID  UnitStatus  UnitDate    UnitTime        
1       Asleep      1/8/2015    22:00
1       Awake       1/8/2015    8:00
2       Awake       1/8/2015    7:00
3       Asleep      1/8/2015    5:00
1       Asleep      1/8/2015    0:00
2       Asleep      1/7/2015    23:00
3       Awake       1/7/2015    13:00
1       Awake       1/7/2015    8:30
2       Awake       1/7/2015    6:50
```

Wanted history records (just the first/latest records)

```
UnitID  UnitStatus  UnitDate    UnitTime
1       Asleep      1/08/2015   22:00
2       Awake       1/08/2015   7:00
3       Asleep      1/08/2015   5:00
```

Wanted End Result (a really big query, dumbed down, sorted by UnitLastHeardFrom)

```
UnitID  UnitStatus  UnitDate    UnitTime    UnitGoingTo UnitComingFrom  UnitLastHeardFrom   UnitVehicle
2       Awake       1/08/2015   7:00        New York    Chicago         6:00                Unit20
1       Asleep      1/08/2015   22:00       Denver      Los Angelos     5:00                Unit10
3       Asleep      1/08/2015   5:00        London      Phoenix         4:00                Unit30
```

---

@Juan Carlos Oropeza
I'm still working through your first solution.  It's giving me an error.

```
WITH cteTbl AS (
    SELECT
         UnitID
         MAX( CAST(UnitDate AS CHAR(10) ) || ' ' || CAST (UnitTime as CHAR(10) ) ) AS cteMaxTime
    FROM
         myHistoryTableCTE
)
SELECT
    UnitID
    UnitStatus
    ,CAST(UnitDate AS CHAR(10)) || ' ' || CAST(UnitTime AS CHAR(10)) AS dattim
    FROM
        myHistoryTable
INNER JOIN cteTbl
    on myHistoryTable.UnitID = myHistoryTableCTE.UnitID
         AND myHistoryTable.dattim = myHistoryTableCTE.cteMaxTime -- error says column dattim does not exist in myHistoryTable
```

Your second solution works on its own, until I add my main query logic to it.  I tried two ways.

```
/* Main Select Logic  */
/* Main From Logic */
/* LEFT JOIN bunch of stuff */
LEFT JOIN 
(
    WITH history AS --ERROR: AS is not expected.
    (
        /* Insert second solution */
        where history.rowNumber = 1
    )
) as h
ON mainTableID = h.UnitID

WHERE

/*Main Where logic*/
/*Group By logic*/
/*Order By logic*/
```

And then I tried this.

```
WITH history AS
    (
        /* Insert second solution */
    )
) as h

/* Main Select Logic  */
,SUM(CASE WHEN /* condition */ THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IfLogic, SUM(CASE WHEN /* condition */ THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IfMoreLogic --If I remove this line and its associated Left Join logic below, the query works.  There's nothing that stands out to me in this function.  I have a MAX function too and I don't need to remove that one.
/* Main From Logic */
/* LEFT JOIN bunch of stuff */

LEFT JOIN history
    ON mainTableID = h.UnitID

WHERE

/*Main Where logic*/

AND history.rowNumber = 1

/*Group By logic*/
/*Order By logic*/
--ERROR: Code 6 OLAP Functions are not supported.
```

Comment: I am trying to understand the question to answer. Your goal is to get the first record of a history table. In the tables above, the history table is the first one, correct? The one with 10 records

Comment: Yes, the first table is the history table.  I'm trying to get the first/latest record of every unit.

Comment: very weird your `UnitTime` doesnt have `date` part

Comment: Have you tried grouping by unitID having the least/greatest UnitTime?

Comment: Well, the date part is a different column that I didn't choose to show.  Let me fix that.

Comment: @Erick I believe I have and one of the problems with Group By is that I also need the status.  What ends up happening is when I link to the main table, I have the greatest time for Asleep and the greatest time for Awake, and I only want the current available status.

Comment: Your biggest problem here is going to be performance - the fact that date/time are separate columns is going to bite you.  If possible, you should get a single timestamp column instead; you can still query it for dates as easily, although time-of-day is harder (but not as meaningful without date anyways).

Comment: I do not have control over the database.  I've attempted to concatenate the date and time into a column in my query, but reusing that column in the same query brings up an error saying that the column doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First you calculate the max entry for each unit
- Then join back to your `history` table to find what is the unit status at that time

.

```
WITH lastTime as (
    SELECT UnitID, MAX(UnitTime) lTime
    FROM history 
    GROUP BY UnitID
)
SELECT h.UnitID,  h.UnitStatus,  h.UnitTime
FROM history h
inner join lastTime l
  on h.UnitID = l.UnitID
 and h.lTime = l.lTime
```

Other solution is using `row_number() over partition`, in this case each `UnitID` hava a sequence from 1..n starting the latest `UnitTime`

```
WITH lastTime as (
    SELECT 
         UnitID, 
         UnitStatus,
         UnitTime,
         row_number() over(partition by UnitID order by UnitTime desc) as rn, 
    FROM history 
)
SELECT l.UnitID,  l.UnitStatus,  l.UnitTime
FROM lastTime l
WHERE l.rn = 1
```

Comment: Im confused by your sample data, not sure if you want `min` or `max`, because  in your desire result `unitID=1` return `max()= 22h` but 2,3 return `min() = 7h and 5h`

Comment: I've added a date column in my sample data.  It seems that if I do max(cast date as char(10) || ' ' || cast time as char(10)) it works... until I start to try figuring out the time issue.  I think the other solution is better and cleaner, but when I try it with my main query cte at top, I get a " An OLAP function is not supported for this query" error.  And if I try it with my main query, instead of on top, doing a left join (cte lastTime as ( yadada )) on id = id, I get an error saying "AS not expected."

Comment: If you need me to explain my comment, I'll be happy to edit my question with my attempts on your answer

Comment: I do know that your row_number() over partition solution worked separately outside my main query.

Comment: Yes you should do that. Also i dont have a db2 server to try my query, but i search for question to see proper sintaxys. So If you are having trouble you should try minimize the query to see what part you have error. Looks like you have problem with second version but first version work ok?

Comment: It works!  I ended up using the first version.  The only alteration I was missing was doing a `Timestamp(UnitDate, UnitTime)`.